# Why does the Mandelbrot fractal appear when plotting $\underbrace{x\cos(x\cos( \cdots x\cos}_9(x))))$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fractals, chaos-theory

[image]

while plotting the function $x\cos(x\cos(x\cos(x\cos(x\cos(x\cos(x\cos(x\cos(x\cos(x)))))))))$
using matplotlib in python I found the mandelbrot fractal.

What is the reason that the mandelbrot fractal appears in the process and what literature should I read to learn more about this. Maybe the mandelbrot fractal appears in more places where you iterate a function over and over again.
here is the code

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import cmath

# Defining the function to map a complex function
def map_complex_function(complex_func, real_range, imag_range, color_scheme=("magnitude", "argument", "(10x)/(10x+1)")):
    # Creating the domain
    real_values, imag_values = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(real_range[0], real_range[1], 1000),
                                           np.linspace(imag_range[0], imag_range[1], 1000))
    z_values = real_values + 1j * imag_values

    # Applying the complex function to the domain
    w_values = complex_func(z_values)

    # Extracting the magnitude and argument
    magnitude = np.abs(w_values)
    argument = np.angle(w_values) / (2 * np.pi) % 1

    # Determining brightness based on the provided color scheme
    if color_scheme[2] == "(10x)/(10x+1)":
        brightness = (10 * magnitude) / (10 * magnitude + 1)
    else:
        brightness = magnitude / np.max(magnitude)

    # Creating HSV values
    saturation = np.ones_like(argument)
    hsv_values = np.stack([argument, saturation, brightness], axis=-1)

    # Converting HSV to RGB
    rgb_values = mcolors.hsv_to_rgb(hsv_values)

    # Plotting the image
    plt.imshow(rgb_values, origin='lower', extent=[real_range[0], real_range[1], imag_range[0], imag_range[1]])
    plt.xlabel('Real part')
    plt.ylabel('Imaginary part')
    plt.title(f'Complex map for {complex_func.__name__}')
    plt.colorbar(label='Magnitude (custom scale)')
    plt.show()

def f(z):
    return z*np.cos(z*np.cos(z*np.cos(z*np.cos(z*np.cos(z*np.cos(z*np.cos(z*np.cos(z*np.cos(z)))))))))
    
# Creating the plots
real_range = (0, 6)
imag_range = (-4, 4)
map_complex_function(f, real_range, imag_range, color_scheme=("magnitude", "argument", "(10x)/(10x+1)"))```
````

Comment: It's very much like the Mandelbrot set, but a little different, unless that's just down to the coloring choices.  The self-map $z\to z^2+c$ clearly has some echoes in the near-self-map $z\to 1-\frac {z^2}2+\frac {z^4}{4!}-\dots$

Comment: Complex function plotter interactive link [here](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/#cos(z*cos(z*cos(z*cos(z*cos(z*cos(z*cos(z*cos(z*cos(z))))))))))

Comment: It was really necessary to make the expression that long? Are you on porpuse trying to mess up the formatting of MathJax to make the question difficult to read instead of saying " nesting 14 times" or something like that?

Comment: @jjagmath I was expirmenting while making a program so I wrote what I did but I fix my question to be shorter thank you for your criticism

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fix some $z_0$, define $f(z) = z_0 \cos(z)$, and let
$$ f^n = \underbrace{f\circ f\circ \dotsb \circ f}_{\text{$n$ times}}.$$
Given some point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, the pixel corresponding to $z_0$ in the image is assigned a color based on the value of $f^n(z_0)$ (where $n$ is whatever you choose it to be—in the question, it seems that $n=11$ish).  The precise details aren't all that important—the relevant bit is that if $|f^n(z_0)|$ is large, the corresponding pixel is dark; and if $|f^n(z_0)|$ is small, then the color of the corresponding pixel is determined by the argument of $f^n(z))$ (more or less).  The image in the question is obtained by taking $n\approx 10$ (maybe a bit bigger?  I didn't count all the cosines).

Similarly, fix $z_0$ and define $g(z) = z^2 + z_0$.  Applying the same coloring scheme to points in the complex plane, $g^{n}(z)$, for some largish value of $n$, looks something like

[image]

This image was created using Will Bolden's [Complex Function Visualization tool](https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/%7Epang/161/w17/submit/projects/wbolden/cfp/#z).  [Here](https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/%7Epang/161/w17/submit/projects/wbolden/cfp/#((((((((((((z%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2+z)%5E2%20+%20z) is a link to the configuration which gives the image above, perhaps modulo some checkerboard patterns and/or markers for zero).  Note that this *is* an approximation of the Mandelbrot set.

The visualization of $f^n$ has copies of things which look like the Mandelbrot set because $f$ looks a lot like $g$ for certain values of $z=z_0$.  This can be seen by considering the Taylor series $f$ at $a=2k\pi$ (where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$):

\begin{align}
f(z)
&= z_0 \cos(z) \\
&= \pm z_0 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!} \\
&= \pm z_0 \left( 1 - \frac{(z-a)^2}{2} + \frac{(z-a)^4}{4!} - \frac{(z-a)^6}{6!} + \dotsb \right) \\
&\approx \mp\frac{(z-a)^2}{2}z_0 + z_0 \\
&= C (z-a)^2 + z_0, \\
\end{align}
where the leading sign (the $\pm$ and $\mp$) depends on the parity of $k$, and the value of the constant $C$ will depend on the choice of $z_0$.  For any fixed $a$, this function looks *a lot* like the function $g$, which generates the Mandelbrot set.  This implies that the behaviour of $f^n(z_0)$, when $z_0 \approx 2k\pi$ for some integer $k$, should "look like" the behaviour of $g^n$ around zero.

As such, I would expect to see a little "mini-Mandelbrot" around every integer multiple of $2\pi$ on the real axis.  Moreover, I would expect that they will alternate between two colors (in the original image, I'm guessing teal, which corresponds to the positive real axis; and red, which corresponds to negative real axis).  Finally, the bigger $|z_0|$ is, the larger that leading constant will be, which will make it "harder" for iterates to remain bounded.  Hence I would expect the "mini-Mandelbrots" to get smaller and smaller as they get farther from the origin.